# Range slider does not work in mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried implementing jquery range slider, Its working perfectly in Computer but while browsing from mobile, its not working. Any suggestion, why is this so?

The Link where I implemented slider is: http://custmr.co.uk/pricing/

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery ui doesn't have touch support. You should use it with jQuery-ui touch punch.

Just add the script after jQuery ui:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome i'm glad your problem is fix